# CSS with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css

```
_______________________________________________
|                                             |
|             Header                          |
|_____________________________________________|
         |                           | 
         |                           |
         |                           |
         |          Content          |
         |                           |
         |                           |
         |                           |
         |                           |         
_______________________________________________
|                                             |
|             Footer                          |
|_____________________________________________|
```

Hello, I want to make a layout like the idea above. The idea is that if you have little content the footer to stay down there, stuck.

My problems are:

- I can not leave my Header width 100% and leave the footer on the screen when you have little content as it travels
- When using IE, ruins everything

http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/8Yek8/

Comment: check this out...http://jsfiddle.net/KTgrS/

Comment: For IE problems, try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` into your `<head>`

Comment: What do you mean by 100%? Width? Height? Do you want a header and footer fixed to the page or to the window (with the content scrolling under it)? Please clarify.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/8s4K8/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sticky+footer

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ is this what you're searching for?

Comment: ppollono has a solution if what you want are *fixed* headers (attached to the window) and footers. Take a look at the links that were posted for *sticky* footers (attached to the page).

Comment: I actually wanted with little content to set footer at bottom of page width 100%, and if you have higher contents than the page footer stay fixed at the end of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What I got the idea from your issue is if you use position:fixed in css for footer and make it bottom:0; it will work. Hope this is helpful.